# BCC not correctly handled when sendin a mail out of an Oracle database via MS Exchange

Tags: oracle, bcc

I send e-mails from an Oracle database via MS Exchange. For this I use "UTL_SMTP". But if I use "BCC", I see the header unchanged in the mail source of all recipients. So everyone can see who is in BCC.

What's wrong there? Do I have to consider anything else with BCC?

Here is my test code (with pseudo mail host):

```
DECLARE
    p_to        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'recipient1@test.com';
    p_bcc       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'recipient2@test.com';
    p_from      VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'no-reply@test.com';
    p_subject   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'Testmail (BCC)';
    p_message   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'Testmail BCC.';
    p_smtp_host VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := 'sm.test.com';
    p_smtp_port NUMBER             := 25;
    
    l_mail_conn UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
    l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
    
    UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
    UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
    
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn,p_to);
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn,p_bcc);
    
    UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
    
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'BCC: ' || p_bcc || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    
    
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

    UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

E-mail source of "recipient1@test.com":

```
...
To: <recipient1@test.com>
BCC: <recipient2@test.com>
From: <no-reply@test.com>
Subject: Testmail (BCC)
...
```

Thanks!
Volker

Answer (score 1):

Well, after googling again for an hour I found out, that I must not set the BCC header. BCC must only be sent with rcpt() function.

I found the solution [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=email-through-oracle). The answer sais "... For example, sending a BCC is simple -- you just RCPT the person and DON"T put them in a CC: or TO: record. ...". And that was the problem, I was setting a "BCC" header. In the RFCs I found the header "BCC", so I added it, unfortunately.

Best, Volker

Comment: It is good that you found a solution to your problem; it would be even better if you included a link to the documentation and/or a quote from the documentation where you found the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added it to my answer.